# Panel mount micro USB extension cables: how do they work?

Tags: usb, panel-mounting

I need to expose the usb port on an arduino pro micro to the outside of a project box. I've been looking for some sort of panel mount extension cable, and all I've been able to find are ones that look like this:

[image]

I'm confused about why the middle of the plug is recessed like that; isn't that going to result in the usb port itself sitting *behind* the panel, rather than flush with the panel? I haven't been able to find a picture of one of these in use anywhere to verify.

If it matters, the case to which I'll be mounting this is a thin tin (formally it held pirate not-actually-band-aids; think an altoids tin, but slightly bigger).

Comment: It's not clear that the face of the connector isn't flush with the mounting surfaces.  But regardless, this is a question you'd have to pursue with the manufacturer.  The standard advice here is "no data sheet, no sale" - in this case it's particularly the *mechanical drawing* you need.

Comment: that connector shell is fairly large, compared to the size of the Altoids tin ... you can put the wide part on the outside of the tin

Comment: Right, as I said, not actually an altoids tin: larger box, but similar thickness of material.

Comment: take a closer look at the picture ... the plug is not recessed ... shave the ears down so that they are flush with the recessed area if you like

Comment: I see that, but it looks like it's flush with the non-recessed ends of the connector. I would expect it to be slightly proud so that it would extend into/through the panel into which it was mounted.

Comment: It looks like it was designed to fit the same cutout that you would use for a DE-9 (or HD15) D-sub connector.